# Primefaces p:calendar inside overlaypanel

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces, calendar

I try to show a pop-up calendar in a overlaypanel, but when I click in the associated input box the calendar is displayed behind the overlaypanel and i cannot see the header of the calendar. Here is my code:

```
<p:overlayPanel id="advancedSearchPanel" styleClass="ui-advanced-search-overlay"  dismissable="false" for="advancedSearch" hideEffect="fade" my="right top" dynamic="true">
    <h:form>
                 <h:panelGrid>
                     <!--<p:inputText  
    value="#{searchForm.processSubject}"></p:inputText>-->
                     <p:outputLabel  value="Pesquisa:" for="type"/>
                     <h:selectOneMenu id="type" value="#{searchForm.type}">
                         <f:selectItems value="#{searchForm.listProcessTypes}"/>
                     </h:selectOneMenu>
                     <p:inputText  value="#{searchForm.processNumber}"></p:inputText>
                     <p:calendar id="datetime" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
                     <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{searchForm.save}"></p:commandButton>
                  </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:overlayPanel>
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `p:overlay`'s `appendToBody="true"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is partially solved because the p:calendar appears in the overlaypanel which is included in <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-header" and the overlaypanel now appears behind this div. What can i do to bring to front the overlaypanel?

Comment: Try adding a `style` attribute with `z-index:999; !important`... and you can set any high number on the `z-index`...

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by setting

```
dismissable = "false"
```